# MQTT Recived Message ID in C#

Tags: c#, mqtt

Hello I am new to this but I am developing a client to Mosquitto broker.

It works fine, but I want to know how could I add the Sender Id to the message.

i.e. Message From "Client1" : "LightON"

This is how I handle the subscription

```
private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        IPAddress HostIP;
        HostIP = IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        clientSub = new MqttClient(HostIP);
        clientSub.MqttMsgPublishReceived += new MqttClient.MqttMsgPublishEventHandler(EventPublished);
    }
    catch (InvalidCastException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR ON LOAD" + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

The Publish Event is :

```
private void EventPublished(Object sender, uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages.MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SetText("Recevied Message..");
        SetText("The Topic is:" + e.Topic);
        SetText("*Message: " + System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message));
        SetText(""); 
    }
    catch (InvalidCastException ex)
    {
    }
}
```

And I am using the M2mqtt library.

Comment: I'm not familuat with this library, but if you are setting the clientId `string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
client.Connect(clientId); ` its not coming through as the `sender` ?

Comment: @Pogrindis  I dont generate them, I use textbox to let the client enters the ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is to add it to the message payload yourself.

There is no concept of a publisher id in the MQTT headers. Client IDs are only to identify clients to the broker, not end to end.

Comment: Thats quite interesting actually, seems intentional too.. Any particular reason for this ?

Comment: Yes, in a Pub/Sub world you should not care, you listen to a topic, who puts data on that topic is irrelevant.

Comment: @hardillb Ok is the anyway to fetch channels from broker. I mean is there any possible way for the client to know which channels are now on the broker !!?

Comment: if by channels you mean topics, then no because a topic only really exists at the point a message is published to it, then the broker checks which clients have a matching subscription and delivers the message to those clients